# CaffeineCacheManager vs SimpleCacheManager

Tags: spring, spring-cache

May I know different between CaffeineCacheManager and SimpleCacheManager?

As description CaffeineCacheManager is Lazy cache, but what is lazy cache, in what situation I should pick CaffeineCacheManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of [all the different cache providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html) first and notice how their APIs differ. The `Simple Cache` manager is Spring's default cache manager that's used if you don't specify a cache manager. It's 'simple' because its underlying implementation uses a Java [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and it doesn't give you a whole lot of customization options.

The `Caffeine Cache` manager is slightly different in that there a more configuration-driven customization options such as having the ability to specify the cache `timeout expiry limit` (in order to 'bust' the cache after a certain time period) and the cache `maximum size limit` in order to limit the capacity of the cache. The default cache manager does not give you this configurability.

My team used the `Caffeine Cache` manager on a project recently and I can definitely recommend it.

In terms of your question about a 'lazy' cache. Have a read of [lazy instatiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) more broadly. Essentially it only loads what it needs when it needs it (upon a cache access) rather than loading the entire thing all at once.